# Accessing Files Through Qemu

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm working on an operation system programming project, and I'm starting to work on the file system, because I'm running my operation system on QEMU I kind stumped into a problem. My idea was so simulate a disk using an .img file, but because I'm running the operation system on a virtual machine I can't really access the file, how can I access the file in order to write and read from it?

Comment: Do you mean you need to access the file system of a VM from the host? If it is so; you can use guestmount command from libguestfs-tools package.

Comment: Or if you want to access the same files at the same time consider (with a new Ubtuntu) https://libvirt.org/kbase/virtiofs.html (Or with an older Ubuntu 9pfs https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#filesystems)

Comment: @NK_ I need to be able to read and write into a file that is located in my host OS ( aka my ubuntu ) Through QEMU, because I'm trying to make a file system I need to simulate a disk somehow, and to do so I thought about doing it with a file, but without being able to read and write from it I can't do anything.